# Returning a date from google scripts to a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function (found it online) that calculates the next working day and returns a date. However, the number shows up in the cell in Google Sheets as a number and I cannot figure out why. I have checked the formatting of the cell and it is set for a date format. Here's the code:

```
function nextWorkDay(fromDate){
  fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate()+1);
  if (fromDate.getDay()==0) fromDate.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
  else if (fromDate.getDay()==6) fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate()+2);
  return fromDate;
}
```

I have tested this in a standard html page and it works fine. I know I am missing something but I can't seem to find it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT: I thought some examples might help. If I use the following formula in a cell:

```
=nextWorkDay(DATE(2018,11,14))
```

I get a value of 1542258000000 as the result in the cell.

I created a jsFiddle to show how it works in javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/bazianm/o4kyv2p6/

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Your code and example work perfectly for me. The value you're seeing is a form of Unix time. Assuming it's in cell A1, you can convert it with this formula `=(((A1/1000/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)`

Comment: Is the cell formatted as date?

Comment: Yes. Definitely.